# Print JSON timestamp format using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want this output for my **JSON**, How can I do this timestamp format using **PHP**?

```
 **This 1403375851930 is not equal to 2015-09-03 11:40:46**

{"newsfeed":[{"timeStamp": "1403375851930}]}"
```

this is my **Current Output**

`{"newsfeed":[{"timestamp":"2015-09-03 11:40:46"}]}`

my **PHP Code**

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM newsfeed';
//execute the query using mysql_query
$result = mysql_query($query);
//then using while loop, it will display all the records inside the table
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$json['newsfeed'][] = $row;
}
?>
```

Output(**the timestamp is in the last**)

```
{"newsfeed":[{"0":"54","id":"54","1":"55e869fe755ea8.63620266","unique_id":"55e869fe755ea8.63620266","2":"News and Events","type":"News and Events","3":"Cosmos","title":"Cosmos","4":"http:\/\/brmhelpdesk.comlu.com\/BRMhelpdesk\/uploads\/cosmos.jpg","image":"http:\/\/brmhelpdesk.comlu.com\/BRMhelpdesk\/uploads\/cosmos.jpg","5":"asd'[sajfpsdgfg\r\nfdfhfgkljghhdsf\r\nasfdjkhjlkjghjhsdfa\r\nasfgfdgjjlkjhgsffsad","description":"asd'[sajfpsdgfg\r\nfdfhfgkljghhdsf\r\nasfdjkhjlkjghjhsdfa\r\nasfgfdgjjlkjhgsffsad","6":"http:\/\/www.brmhelpdesk.comlu.com\/BRMhelpdesk\/uploads\/lugo.png","profilePic":"http:\/\/www.brmhelpdesk.comlu.com\/BRMhelpdesk\/uploads\/lugo.png","7":"2015-09-03 11:40:46","timestamp":"2015-09-03 11:40:46"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what do you is this :

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2015-09-03 11:40:46');
```

In your case :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row['timestamp'] = strtotime($row['timestamp']);
    $json['newsfeed'][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: In my Loop I will declare them 1 by 1 then print as an array again?

Comment: thanks! it works! but i got another problem is printed as Jan 17, 1970 rofl well anyway you answered what i need thanks again man!